# Program printing "null" when trying to find the middle word in a set of three Strings

Tags: java

Problem:

> Given 3 words w1,w2 and w3 as input, output the word that will come in between in a dictionary. without using any string functions

```
public String middleWord(String word1,String word2,String word3){

      String str="";
      for(int i=0;(i<word1.length()||i<word2.length()||i<word3.length());i++){
      char ch1=word1.charAt(i);
      char ch2=word2.charAt(i);
      char ch3=word3.charAt(i);
      if(ch1<=ch2 && ch2<=ch3)
      str=str+ch2;
      else if(ch2<=ch1 && ch1<=ch3)
      str=str+ch1;
      else if(ch1<=ch3 && ch3<=ch2)
      str=str+ch3;

      }
      return str;
   }
```

When I run my code some test cases return null, what to do?

```
Testcase |  Pass/Fail  |     Parameters      | Actual Output | Expected Output
   #1    |     Pass    | 'cat' 'bat' 'rat'   |    cat        |  cat
   #2    |     Fail    | 'go' 'went' 'gone'  |    null       |  gone
```

Comment: The task is to *choose* a word, not to build a new `String`. Please try again.

Comment: As expected from looking at the code, it throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. That's because you loop `i` while less than *longest* word, so `charAt(i)` fails on shorter word.

Comment: Your code **can't** return `null`, so the entire premise of the question is flawed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i dont missunderstood what you are trying to do, i think that this simple changes would work...

```
public static String middleWord(String word1, String word2, String word3) {

    for (int i = 0; (i < word1.length() || i < word2.length() || i < word3.length()); i++) {
        char ch1 = 10000;
        char ch2 = 10000;
        char ch3 = 10000;
        if(word1.length() > i){
            ch1 = word1.charAt(i);
        }
        if(word2.length() > i){
            ch2 = word2.charAt(i);
        }
        if(word3.length() > i){
            ch3 = word3.charAt(i);
        }
        if (ch1 <= ch2 && ch2 <= ch3) {
            return word2;
        } else if (ch2 <= ch1 && ch1 <= ch3) {
            return word1;
        } else if (ch1 <= ch3 && ch3 <= ch2) {
            return word3;
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

the problem in your code is that you are concatenating the chars, and when you have decided which is the middle word, you only need to return it.

Comment: Since it looks like OP is trying a homework problem, it's probably better to leave out the ternary operations.

Comment: @Trobbins thanks for the appreciation, maybe now its more easy to read.

Comment: Since you want shorter word sorted first ('car' < 'cars'), you want the missing char to be 0, not 10000. --- You also want to change all the `<=` to `<`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, e.g. first `if` statement will return word2 when word1 < word2 < word3, but no `if` statement handles word3 < word2 < word1.

Comment: @melli-182 thaks your code passes all test case but ,i din't understand why we are using( char ch1 = 10000;) ,if you explain me whats its usage.

Comment: @Trobbins I disagree. If this is a homework question, then we shouldn't *give* him the answer, but rather *guide* him to an answer. We shouldn't be writing his homework. If not, then ternary operations are fine to use. --- Fine line to walk, and I don't know the policy on doing other peoples homework, but still.

Comment: @Andreas Boiled down my comment amounts to this: If OP can't solve the above problem on his own, they likely do not understand ternary operations and should be omitted from any possible solution.

Comment: @PallaviSingh This code *doesn't* pass all tests. --- Try `"sat", "soot", "sit"`, `"soot", "sit", "sat"`, and `"sit", "sat", "soot"`, and you get "soot", "sit", "sat". Removing `=` gets "sit", null, "sit". --- Try `"car", "cart", "cars"`, `"cart", "cars", "car"`, and `"cars", "car", "cart"`, and you get "cart", "cars", "car". Removing `=` gets null, "cart", "cart". Changing 10000 to 0 gets "cars", null, "cars". --- **Failed**

Comment: @Andreas Please, its obvious that you have done the best answer of the word, please... show it to us!

Comment: @PallaviSingh i choose this value to get something to compare, maybe a value like 0 its better to asign in order to get a better comparison.

Comment: @melli-182 -ok ,thanks, i am new on java try to learn strings ,if you have any links where i can get good exercises please forward me.

Comment: @melli-182 As requested, working code added as an answer. Don't know if it's the *best* answer, but the work *works*.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String middleWord(String word1,String word2,String word3){     
   int i=0;
   int j=0;
   int k=0;
    char ch1= '\u0000';
    char ch2= '\u0000';
    char ch3= '\u0000';
 while(i<word1.length()||j<word2.length()||k<word3.length()){
        if(i<word1.length()){
        ch1=word1.charAt(i++);
        }
        if(j<word2.length()){
        ch2=word2.charAt(j++);
        }
        if(k<word3.length()){
       ch3=word3.charAt(k++);
        }
        if(ch2>ch1&&ch2<ch3)
         return word2;
        if(ch1>ch2&&ch1<ch3)
         return word1;
        if(ch3>ch1&&ch3 < ch2)
         return word3;
         if(ch1==ch2){
             i++;
             j++;
             while(i<word1.length()||j<word2.length()){
                if(i<word1.length()){
                ch1=word1.charAt(i);
                i++;
                 }
             if(j<word2.length()){
               ch2=word2.charAt(j);
               j++;
             }
             if(ch2>ch1)
             return word2;
             else
              return word1;
            }
           }
        else if(ch2==ch3){
            j++;
            k++;
            while(j<word2.length()||k<word3.length()){
              if(j<word2.length()){
               ch1=word1.charAt(j);
               j++;
               }
              if(k<word3.length()){
               ch2=word2.charAt(k);
                k++;
              }
             if(ch2>ch1)
             return word3;
             else
             return word2;
            }
          }
        else if(ch1==ch3){
            i++;
            k++;
            while(i<word1.length()||k<word3.length()){
                if(i<word1.length()){
                 ch1=word1.charAt(i);
                 i++;
                }
             if(k<word3.length()){
                ch2=word3.charAt(k);
                k++;
             }
             if(ch2>ch1)
             return word3;
             else
             return word1;
            }
         }
      }
   return "bad";   
}
```

Comment: This code passed all test cases.I did not use any build function to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code passed all test cases not using any build function in string.

> Given 3 words w1,w2 and w3 as input, output the word that will come in between in a dictionary.

```
public static String middleWord(String word1, String word2, String word3) {

    int i=0;
   int j=0;
   int k=0;
    char ch1= '\u0000';
    char ch2= '\u0000';
    char ch3= '\u0000';
 while(i<word1.length()||j<word2.length()||k<word3.length()){
        if(i<word1.length()){
        ch1=word1.charAt(i++);
         }
        if(j<word2.length()){
        ch2=word2.charAt(j++);
         }
        if(k<word3.length()){
       ch3=word3.charAt(k++);
        }
        if(ch2>ch1&&ch2<ch3)
         return word2;
        if(ch1>ch2&&ch1<ch3)
         return word1;
        if(ch3>ch1&&ch3 < ch2)
         return word3;
         if(ch1==ch2){
             i++;
             j++;
             String res=compare(word1,word2,i,j);
             return res;
        }
        else if(ch2==ch3){
            j++;
            k++;
            String res=compare(word2,word3,j,k);
              return res;
        }
        else if(ch1==ch3){
            i++;
            k++;
            String res=compare(word1,word3,i,k);
              return res;
         }
 }
   return "bad";
}  
public String compare(String str1,String str2,int n1,int n2){
   char ch1= '\u0000';
    char ch2= '\u0000';
while(n1<str1.length()||n2<str2.length()){
                if(n1<str1.length()){
                 ch1=str1.charAt(n1);
                 n1++;
                }
             if(n2<str2.length()){
                ch2=str2.charAt(n2);
                n2++;
             }
             if(ch2>ch1)
             return str2;
             else
             return str1;
            }
            return "poor";
}
 }
```

I short my program by making a function which compare two chars of giving   strings.When any two chars are same then we use this function to choose which one come first in dictionary and which is second.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in comments, and not acted on, the code in the question has the following problems:

- The code is trying to build a new string, however the task is to choose a word, so the code is off the mark from the beginning.
- The code throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- Even if it didn't, there is no code path whatsoever that could make the code return `null`.

Therefore the code is flawed, and doesn't behave as described. This totally fails the *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable* principle for Stack Overflow, in particular the *Verifiable* part. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Also the logic fails by trying to compare one letter at a time. If the input was "aa", "bb", "ac", then answer should be "ac", because "aa" < "ac" < "bb", but comparing one letter at a time cannot detect this without some major state tracking.

Assuming that "without using any string functions" means that you can't use any *built-in* functions you could just write your own compare.

```
public static String middleWord(String word1, String word2, String word3) {
    int cmp12 = compareWords(word1, word2);
    int cmp13 = compareWords(word1, word3);
    int cmp23 = compareWords(word2, word3);
    if (cmp12 == 0 || cmp13 == 0 || cmp23 == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found equal words: " + word1 + ", " + word2 + ", " + word3);
    if (cmp12 < 0) { // word1 < word2
        if (cmp23 < 0) // word2 < word3
            return word2; // word1 < word2 < word3
        if (cmp13 < 0) // word1 < word3
            return word3; // word1 < word3 < word2
        return word1; // word3 < word1 < word2
    }
    if (cmp13 < 0) // word1 < word3
        return word1; // word2 < word1 < word3
    if (cmp23 < 0) // word2 < word3
        return word3; // word2 < word3 < word1
    return word2; // word3 < word2 < word1
}
private static final int compareWords(String word1, String word2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
        if (i == word2.length())
            return 1; // word1 > word2 (word2 shorter and compared equal until now)
        char ch1 = word1.charAt(i);
        char ch2 = word2.charAt(i);
        if (ch1 < ch2)
            return -1; // word1 < word2
        if (ch1 > ch2)
            return 1; // word1 > word2
    }
    if (word2.length() > word1.length())
        return -1; // word1 < word2 (word1 shorter and compared equal until now)
    return 0; // word1 == word2
}
```

Testing the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Expecting 'sit':");
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("sat", "soot", "sit"));
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("soot", "sit", "sat"));
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("sit", "sat", "soot"));
    System.out.println("Expecting 'cars':");
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("car", "cart", "cars"));
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("cart", "cars", "car"));
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("cars", "car", "cart"));
    System.out.println("Expecting 'ac':");
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("aa", "ac", "bb"));
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("ac", "bb", "aa"));
    System.out.println("  " + middleWord("bb", "aa", "ac"));
}
```

Output:

```
Expecting 'sit':
  sit
  sit
  sit
Expecting 'cars':
  cars
  cars
  cars
Expecting 'ac':
  ac
  ac
  ac
```

Comment: the code fails, if one of the words are null, it throws NPE.

Comment: @Andreas ,your code have only one flaws if i have input- 'hello' 'hello' 'hello' , then your code output fails and gives null.

Comment: @PallaviSingh True, but the question was stated as a "dictionary", and words are *not* repeated in a dictionary, so repeating a word is an error. If repeated words are valid, the question should have stated so.

Comment: @melli-182 Yup. As designed. Question was to find middle of 3 words. If a word is missing, that's an error, and you get an error.